# Extern undefined symbol

Tags: c, dll, shared-libraries, extern

I am building a user defined shell where the shell dynamically links libraries

I have the following snippet from the main file that contains the global variable declarations...

```
char *prompt = "upsh";
int main()
{ ...
```

then I have a shared library as follows...

```
extern char *prompt;

int setprompt(char *argv[]) {
    prompt = argv[1];
    return 0;
}
```

my problem is that when I link the library from the main program I get the error

```
./setprompt.so: undefined symbol: prompt
```

...maybe this is a compilation issue?

Comment: please provide the compilation steps.

Answer (score 1):

As Naveem Kumar commented, you should provide compilation steps. Does the following reproduce what you meant? This worked in my laptop.

**Makefile**

```
all: main
libsetprompt.so: setprompt.c
    gcc -fPIC -DPIC -shared setprompt.c -o libsetprompt.so
main: main.c libsetprompt.so
    gcc main.c -o main -L. -lsetprompt
clean:
    rm main libsetprompt.so
```

**main.c**

```
char *prompt = "upsh";
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ return 0; }
```

**setprompt.c**

```
extern char *prompt;
int setprompt(char *argv[])
{
    prompt = argv[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. what is the -lsetprompt option?

Comment: What error do you get with this example? BTW, -L indicates where to find libraries at link time and -lname searches for libname.a or libname.so at that stage. Also, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so as the libsetprompt.so can be found at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a comilation issue. If i get it right, you have a console application, which means that argc and argv must be passed to the main function in order to use them, but they are not passed. I guess your problem is that you call `int setprompt(char *argv[])` without actually passing argv[]. But i may be wrong, more code would help to tell for sure.

But probably instead of `int main()` there should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: This isn't the case, I declare `char *argv[]` in a later place in the code